# Alamofire 4.0.1 does not work in Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, xcode8, carthage

I just updated `Alamofire` to the latest version (4.0.1) by using `Carthage`. I am also working in `Xcode 8.1` and `Swift 3.0.1`

After this update, when I try to build my iOS app in Xcode I get this error regarding `Alamofire`:

> module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.1

I've been looking for information about this issue in `GitHub` and the only thing I found is [this issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1745), that is related to warnings when updating `Alamofire` that I also get.

Has somebody else experienced this issue? Should this work for `Xcode 8.1` and `Swift 3.0.1` but am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

use this command

```
 carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries
```

this will compile the Alamofire to local language (Swift 3.0.1).
I think this will solve your problem